# return and echo my array from a function

Tags: php, error-handling

I have a function that returns either a value into a variable if it is successful or it returns an errors array. see part of it below.

```
function uploadEmploymentDoc($var, $var2){

$ERROR = array();

if(empty($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'])){
$ERROR[] = "You must upload a file!";
}

//find the extensions
$doctypeq = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `DocType` WHERE `DocMimeType` = '$fileType'");
$doctype = mysql_fetch_array($doctypeq);
$docnum = mysql_num_rows($doctypeq);
if($docnum == 0){
$ERROR[] = "Unsupported file type"; 
}

if(empty($ERROR)){
// run my code
return $var;
} else{
return $ERROR;
}
```

then when I run my code

```
$result =  uploadEmploymentDoc(1, 2);

if($result !=array()){
// run code
} else {
   foreach($result as $er){
   echo $er."<br>";
   }
}
```

Now my question is this.  Why is my function running my code and not showing me an error when I upload an unsupported document type.  Am I defining my foreach loop correctly?  For some reason I cant get my errors back.

Comment: what's the question exactly?

Comment: pass $_FILES as argument of function too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try use

```
$result =  uploadEmploymentDoc(1, 2);
if(!is_array($result)){
    // run code
} else {
   foreach($result as $er){
       echo $er."<br>";
   }
}
```

Probably will be better add parameter by reference to function for the errors array. From function return "false" if error and value if no error occurred.

Comment: You solved this before I even asked the question.  Ill accept your answer when it will let me thank you

Answer (score 3):

you should write like this-

```
if(is_array($result)){
   foreach($result as $er){
    echo $er."<br>";
   }
} else {
  //your code for handling error
}
```

You can get more info :https://www.php.net/is_array

Comment: Probably you are the only one who understood his question :)

Comment: just saying.. cuz i didn't get it at the first sight.